# Ubuntu taking forever to turn off

Tags: shutdown

I have a pretty new installation of Ubuntu 19.04, I have no many things installed and I did very little customization.

I put the OS on a dedicated ssd in my computer.

Problem is Ubuntu is very very slow at shutting down: if I command the shutdown (either from gnome or terminal) it gets stuck on the Ubuntu purple screen for good 10 minutes before turning off. My pc is also very high end, so I really can't find any explanation for this behavior.
Can you help me troubleshoot?

Comment: press ESC when shutting down and see what is preventing the shutdown. Usually there is 120s or 2x120seconds delay if something does not stop in time until it gets forcefully killed. Maybe some mounted directory or some application that doesn't stop its processes correctly.

Comment: Maybe you installed some packages that are obsolete and no longer used, so they don't shutdown normally. Install Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) and select *Installed (local or obsolete)* from the pane on the left side. The local installed packages are OK. See if you can find any obsolete packages and uninstall them. But first try pLumo's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like MariaDB server can't shutdown, how can I solve?

Comment: Look at this forum question (https://forum.manjaro.org/t/computer-does-not-shut-down-because-of-mariadb/81565).